# How can I disable Nautilus from automatically opening everytime I have my Android phone plugged in

Tags: nautilus

I dev Android apps and I plug in/out android devices all the time. And it is really annoying to have the Nautilus window opening every time.

How can I disable it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install dconf-tools if you haven't done so yet.

Then open Dconf Editor. Ctrl + F and search for media-handling. Disable the "automount-open" option.

This will disable all media, not only your Android phone.

Comment: Or `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount-open 'false'` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Open `dconf-editor` and uncheck `automount-open` checkbox in `media-handling`.

Should be something like this:
[image: dconf-editor]

Comment: Note, there might be couple `media-handling` configurations for other apps too. You'll need to change value under `gnome.desktop.media-handling`.